# How to install ruby and bundler via Chef?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, chef-infra, bundler, chef-recipe

I'm new to `Chef` and I'm trying, for hours now, figure out how to install ruby and install the gem `bundler`, I'm new to `ruby` too.

I would like to clone my repository and execute like this:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec rackup
```

Simple via Shell scripts, but it seems, for now, very difficult with Chef.
Although, I created this recipe:

metadata.rb

```
depends 'apt'
depends 'git'
# depends 'rbenv' -> # very old version
depends 'ruby_rbenv' # -> new version
depends 'application'
depends 'application_ruby'
depends 'build-essential'
```

metadata.rb

```
include_recipe 'git'
include_recipe 'ruby_rbenv::system'
include_recipe 'build-essential'

rbenv_global 'system'

group 'sinatra_app'

user 'sinatra_app' do
  group 'sinatra_app'
  system true
  shell '/bin/bash'
end

# DON'T WORK    
# rbenv_gem "bundler" do
  # action :install
# end

# DON'T WORK
# rbenv_gem "bundler" do
  # ruby_version "2.4.0"
# end

directory '/srv/sinatra-app' do
  owner 'sinatra_app'
  group 'sinatra_app'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
end

application '/srv/sinatra-app' do
  # Application resource properties.
  owner 'sinatra_app'
  group 'sinatra_app'

  # Subresources, like normal recipe code.
  package 'ruby'
  git "/srv/sinatra-app" do
    repository "git://github.com/tnh/sinatra-app.git"
    reference "master"
    action :sync
  end

  # DON'T WORK
  bundle_install do
    deployment true
  end

end
```

But I'm not sure if ruby is being installed properly. And also the `bundle_install` it seems not be working..

And this is my error output:

```
node1-ubuntu     ================================================================================
node1-ubuntu     Error executing action `install` on resource 'application_bundle_install[/srv/sinatra-app]'
node1-ubuntu     ================================================================================
node1-ubuntu     
node1-ubuntu     Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
node1-ubuntu     ------------------------------------
node1-ubuntu     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
node1-ubuntu     ---- Begin output of ["/usr/bin/ruby", "/usr/local/bin/bundle", "install", "--deployment"] ----
node1-ubuntu     STDOUT: 
node1-ubuntu     STDERR: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/local/bin/bundle (LoadError)
node1-ubuntu     ---- End output of ["/usr/bin/ruby", "/usr/local/bin/bundle", "install", "--deployment"] ----
node1-ubuntu     Ran ["/usr/bin/ruby", "/usr/local/bin/bundle", "install", "--deployment"] returned 1
node1-ubuntu     
node1-ubuntu     Cookbook Trace:
node1-ubuntu     ---------------
node1-ubuntu     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/poise-languages/files/halite_gem/poise_languages/command/mixin.rb:207:in `tap'
node1-ubuntu     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/poise-languages/files/halite_gem/poise_languages/command/mixin.rb:207:in `language_command_shell_out!'
node1-ubuntu     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/poise-languages/files/halite_gem/poise_languages/command/mixin.rb:222:in `block in language_command_mixin'
node1-ubuntu     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/poise-ruby/files/halite_gem/poise_ruby/resources/bundle_install.rb:160:in `run_bundler'
node1-ubuntu     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/poise-ruby/files/halite_gem/poise_ruby/resources/bundle_install.rb:119:in `action_install'
node1-ubuntu     
node1-ubuntu     Resource Declaration:
node1-ubuntu     ---------------------
node1-ubuntu     # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/sinatra-app/recipes/default.rb
node1-ubuntu     
node1-ubuntu      68:   bundle_install do
node1-ubuntu      69:     deployment true
node1-ubuntu      70:   end
node1-ubuntu      71:   
node1-ubuntu     
node1-ubuntu     Compiled Resource:
node1-ubuntu     ------------------
node1-ubuntu     # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/sinatra-app/recipes/default.rb:68:in `block in from_file'
node1-ubuntu     
node1-ubuntu     application_bundle_install("/srv/sinatra-app") do
node1-ubuntu       action [:install]
node1-ubuntu       retries 0
node1-ubuntu       retry_delay 2
node1-ubuntu       default_guard_interpreter :default
node1-ubuntu       declared_type :application_bundle_install
node1-ubuntu       cookbook_name "sinatra-app"
node1-ubuntu       recipe_name "default"
node1-ubuntu       parent application[/srv/sinatra-app]
node1-ubuntu       deployment true
node1-ubuntu       parent_ruby nil
node1-ubuntu       gem_binary "/usr/bin/gem"
node1-ubuntu       timeout 900
node1-ubuntu       path "/srv/sinatra-app"
node1-ubuntu     end
node1-ubuntu     
node1-ubuntu     Platform:
node1-ubuntu     ---------
node1-ubuntu     x86_64-linux
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Another option to consider is install the ChefDK package. It includes a full Ruby environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using `application_ruby` which depends on `poise-ruby` so use that. Check out the docs at https://github.com/poise/poise-ruby but short version just add `ruby_runtime 'myapp'` to the application block.

You can also check out [application_examples](https://github.com/poise/application_examples/blob/master/recipes/todo_rails.rb) for a more detailed example. That's for rails but you can probably figure out how to adapt it for [sinatra](https://github.com/poise/application_ruby/blob/master/test/cookbooks/application_ruby_test/recipes/sinatra.rb]).